# Expectation of operator norm for a matrix with independent sub-gaussian rows

Tags: probability

This is taken from exercise 4.6.2 in High-Dimensional Probability by Roman Vershynin.

**Question:**

Let A be an $m \times n$ matrix whose rows $A_{i}$ are independent, mean zero, sub-gaussian isotropic random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then for any $t \geq 0$ we have
$$
\mathbb{P}[|| \frac{1}{m} A^{T} A - I_{n} || > K^{2} \max (\delta, \delta^{2}) ] < 2 e^{-t^{2}} \ \text{with} \ \delta = C(\sqrt{\frac{n}{m}} - \frac{t}{m})
$$
deduce that
$$
\mathbb{E}[|| \frac{1}{m} A^{T} A - I_{n} || \leq CK^{2}(\sqrt{\frac{n}{m}} - \frac{n}{m})
$$
where $K$ is the maximum of the sub-gaussian norms, $C$ is an absolute constant and $m \gg n$.

**Attempt:**

I've defined $X = ||\frac{1}{m} A^{T} A - I_{n}||/K^{2}$ and by a hint to the exercise I have applied an integral identity which gives
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[X > \delta] d\delta = \int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{P}[X > \delta] d\delta + \int_{1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[X > \delta] d\delta = \int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{P}[X > \delta] d\delta + \int_{1}^{\infty} 2 \delta \mathbb{P}[X > \delta^{2}] d\delta
$$
making a change of variables and applying the concentration inequality yields
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{P}[X > \delta] d\delta + \int_{1}^{\infty} 2 \delta \mathbb{P}[X > \delta^{2}] d\delta \leq \int_{-\sqrt{n}}^{\frac{\sqrt{m}}{C} - \sqrt{n}} 2e^{-t^{2}} \frac{C}{\sqrt{m}} dt + \int_{\frac{\sqrt{m}}{C} - \sqrt{n}}^{\infty} 2 \frac{C}{\sqrt{m}}(\sqrt{n} + t) 2e^{-t^{2}} \frac{C}{\sqrt{m}} dt.
\end{equation*}

I have tried to collect the terms for the integrand $\propto e^{-t^{2}}$ but this doesn't seem to be helpful. Is this the right approach?